# Filter Rows by highest version

Tags: sql

I have a selection of Data. example shown in **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0e8c/9)**

I want to return the highest myValue for each name.

```
NAME    MYVALUE
A1      22
A2      22
A3      21
A4      36
A6      12
A9      5
```

There are 3 rows named A6, I only want the row with the highest value returned.

Comment: select name, max(myvalue) from t group by name

Comment: accepted the first answer as simplicity wins, but the other solution by cms_mgr is a sterling job and also worthy of thanks.

Comment: @platinums then by all means please upvote it ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT NAME,
       max(MYVALUE)
FROM TABLE t
GROUP BY NAME
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0e8c/14)**

Answer (score 1):

I find [analytic functions](http://technology.amis.nl/2004/09/29/analytical-sql-functions-theory-and-examples-part-1-on-the-partition-clause/) a nice way to achieve these kinds of results. In your case that would mean something like:

```
SELECT
    name
    , MAX(myvalue) OVER (PARTITION BY name) AS max_name_value
FROM mytable;
```

Analytic queries IMO offer more flexibility than using a `GROUP BY` alone. The article to which I've linked offers the following example:

> We want to see a list of all departments (that have employees) with the average salary in that department. The following two queries give
>   the same result, one, traditional, with and one without using the
>   group by. The second, analytical query, can more easily be extended to
>   return other information as well, such as an aggregation at a
>   different grouping level.
>
> ```
> select  d.dname
> ,       avg(e.sal)
> from    dept d
>         natural join
>         emp  e
> group
> by      d.dname
> ```
>
> Using an analytical function:
>
> ```
> select  distinct
>         d.dname
> ,       avg(e.sal) over (partition by d.dname)  Average_Salary_in_Dept
> from    dept d
>         natural join
>         emp  e
> ```
>
> Read the analytical part of this query as follows: 'for each record
>   returned, select the average of salary values for all rows in the
>   partition (subset, group) with the same department-name as the current
>   record’s department-name'.

You can also partition by more than one column to show, for example, the maximum ID for each unique combination of name and department, simply by adding more column names to the `PARTITION BY` statement as follows: `(PARTITION BY name, department)`.

Comment: only just realised that, as a result of this question, i became lvl 15, and can now upvote yourquestion. regards